# androidstudio external libraries error

Tags: android, gradle

I include some dependencies (v23.2.0), but in my project, more external libraries that I didn`t include were there(v24.2.1), so Could you help me to figure out where I made the mistakes?
Here is my pic and code .

app.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':common')
    apt 'com.zhy:mpermission-compiler:1.0.0'
    compile project(':umeng')
}
```

common.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.zhy:okhttputils:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.7'
    compile 'com.zhy:autolayout:1.4.5'
    compile 'com.yanzhenjie:permission:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.zhy:mpermission-api:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
}
```

umeng.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: they are definitely added by the other libs you are using?

Answer (score 0):

These Libraries are added with the compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0' library